# How can I join three entities in GreenDao?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, greendao

I tried joining the three entities using the example that GreenDao provides [here](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation//joins/)  but it gives me an error on the last line under the leadTopersonJoin parameter that says "Type Mismatch, expected Join<*, Lead> found Join< Lead, Person>    and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
        var daoSession: DaoSession = Application.getInstance().daoSession
        var queryBuilderLead: QueryBuilder<Lead> = daoSession.leadDao.queryBuilder()
        var leadToPersonJoin: Join<Lead, Person> = queryBuilderLead.join(LeadDao.Properties.LeadPersonId, Person::class.java, PersonDao.Properties.PersonLeadId)
        var personToAddresJoin = queryBuilderLead.join(leadToPersonJoin, PersonDao.Properties.PersonAddressId, Address::class.java, AddressDao.Properties.AddressPersonId)
```

What raw Sql can I use to join the three tables? or alternatively what am I doing wrong in the greenDao Query?

Comment: I don't have any experience with this myself, but from the looks of it you're passing in `Lead, Person` but it's expecting `Person, Lead`.  So maybe change `leadToPersonJoin` to something like `var leadToPersonJoin: Join<Person, Lead> = queryBuilderLead.join(Person::class.java, PersonDao.Properties.PersonLeadId, LeadDao.Properties.LeadPersonId)`.  Basically it seems like you just need to change the order of the returned object from `queryBuilderLead.join` (and maybe redefine `Join<Lead, Person>` to `Join<Person, Lead>`).

Comment: Yes that does fix it the problem is then when I call queryBuilder.list() it returns a list of persons and not leads.  which is not ideal since it necessitates a loop to get all the leads from their person.